# Setting Up WordPress Multisite Domain Mapping in Plesk

Tags: wordpress, dns, plesk, multisite

Our intention is to create a multisite like www.example.com and than point other sites in that multisite installation

www.example2.com
www.example3.com
...

We have set up Wordpress multisite with subdirectories option and also activated Domain Mapping Plugin.

Than we created a child site via Multisite and in Domain Mapping Options we created a domain www.example2.com and conected it with child site via id.

In Plesk than we created a website for www.example2.com with no hosting option.

Also Both of domains  www.example.com and  www.example1.com are hosted in same server.

We are missing something any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First you need create the website on wp multisite from network admin. This will be accessible at ww.example1.com/example2.

Then you need to go to admin of example2 admin and map the domain www.example2.com.

If the domain is pointing to the server where wordpress is (in your case should be as they are on the same place) the site should be available at www.example2.com